# Write a query in MongoDB to find the number of time entry comes in the collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have the mongo collection like this

```
[
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "data_id" : 1,
        "data_test" : "sample1",
        "data_list" : [ 
            "sun"
        ],
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "data_id" : 1,
        "data_test" : "sample2",
        "data_list" : [ 
            "sun",
            "mon"
        ],
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "data_id" : 2,
        "data_test" : "sample3",
        "data_list" : [ 
            "tue"
        ],
    }
    /* 4 */
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "data_id" : 2,
        "data_test" : "sample4",
        "data_list" : [ 
            "tue",
            "wed"
        ],
    }

]
```

I would like to query this to get the count of how many time an element of data_list appear on a single collection where there data_id is the same.
Something like this can be achieved using SQL query like this if the data_list is single element and not a list.

```
Select data_list, count(*) from analytics_customer where data_id = 1 group by data_list
```

The output should be like this if we query for only "data_id" : 1

```
{
    "sun": 2,
    "mon": 1
}
```

The output for "data_id" : 2

```
{
    "tue": 2,
    "wed": 1
}
```

Comment: Use $group. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working mongo playground example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tJjmjcPQWer

Process:

- [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to select the data_ids that you want
- [$unwind](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to get all days as individual records so that we can group them
- [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) unique days and data_ids together. This also enables us to get a [$count](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count-accumulator/#mongodb-group-grp.-count) of the days
- [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again by just data_id (or null) to get a single record per data id, but also [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#mongodb-group-grp.-push) the days so that they are in an array
- [$project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the final format of the document to object using [$arrayToObject](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

It is worth noting that you can change the root of the object, but it is simpler to keep it within the `days` field for manipulation.

An aggregation always results an array rather than a single object.

I'm sure there are better approaches.

Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "data_id": 1 } }, // If you want to aggregate for a single data_id
  {
    $unwind: "$data_list"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        data_id: "$data_id", // If you want to aggregate for all data_ids
        data_list: "$data_list",
        
      },
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.data_id", // If you want to aggregate for all data_ids
      //_id: null,
      days: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.data_list",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data_id: "$_id", // If you want to aggregate for all data_ids
      days: {
        $arrayToObject: "$days"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result (for single id):

```
[
  {
    "data_id": 1,
    "days": {
      "mon": 1,
      "sun": 2
    }
  }
]
```

Result (for all ids):

```
[
  {
    "data_id": 2,
    "days": {
      "tue": 2,
      "wed": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "data_id": 1,
    "days": {
      "mon": 1,
      "sun": 2
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution worked for me. 
The only change I need to make was to update ```$count: {}``` with ```$sum: 1``` as for version 4.4 and under ```$count``` doesn't work.

Comment: One more requirement came in the query. Sometime I will get a list of days I need to avoid for a count. 
For example: 
In the input I got blackListDays = ["mon", "wed"]
So, in this case my output should be 

```
[
  {
    "data_id": 1,
    "days": {
      "sun": 2
    }
  }
]

How can I achieve that?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/)

or if it's a fixed amount of options in the list (7 days of week), you can run `.count()` 7 times and search for each day using [$exists](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).